# I cannot select a class in a svg with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I try this in the script:

```
var key="#US"
d3.select(key).style("fill", "red");
```

it's doesn't work.
But in the console it's work.

I try some function like document.ready or window.onload but it's never work.

After some try I have this :

```
window.onload = function() {
    Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(key){
        d3.select(key).style("fill", "red");
    });
};

Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(key){
    d3.select(key).style("fill", "red");
    console.log("t")
});
```

It's work when the dev console is active and work 1 time out of 4 when not.
Very weird error

Comment: What does the `countries` object look like?

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I downloaded an [SVG world map](https://simplemaps.com/resources/svg-world) and fixed the `class` attributes by replacing spaces with hyphens.

Now, given a map that looks like this:

```js
const countries = {
  '.United-States': true
};
```

Now you can select the US and its territories, and fill them `red`, via:

```js
Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(key) {
  d3.selectAll(key).style("fill", "red");
});
```

#### Working example

If I had time, I could convert all the path class names to a 2 or 3-digit country code to simplify this and make it more in line with your selection strategy.

```js
const svgUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rmkane/4fb74736f090d9145b53e56d7e42989e/raw/e3e6fc625094ab84b3b2381afc447cf109bc601a/world.svg';
const svgContainer = document.querySelector('#svg-container');

const countries = {
  '.United-States': true
};

const parseSvg = (svgText) =>
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml');

(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(svgUrl);
  let svgText = await response.text();
  // Fix path class names
  svgText = svgText.replaceAll(/class="(\w+)\s(\w+)"/g, 'class="$1-$2"');
  const svg = parseSvg(svgText).firstElementChild;
  // Add the SVG
  svgContainer.append(svg);
  // Highlight US and its territories
  Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(key) {
    d3.selectAll(key).style('fill', 'red');
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
<!-- See: https://gist.github.com/rmkane/4fb74736f090d9145b53e56d7e42989e#file-world-svg -->
```

#### Another example

Here is an SVG from [MapSVG](https://mapsvg.com/maps/world):

```js
const svgUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rmkane/4fb74736f090d9145b53e56d7e42989e/raw/ce11d29d4595e9c386bac41efaa82d33b8f07aec/world-2.svg';
const svgContainer = document.querySelector('#svg-container');

const countries = {
  '#US': true
};

const parseSvg = (svgText) =>
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgText, 'image/svg+xml');

(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(svgUrl);
  let svgText = await response.text();
  const svg = parseSvg(svgText).firstElementChild;
  svgContainer.append(svg);
  Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(key) {
    d3.selectAll(key).style('fill', 'red');
  });
})();
```

```css
#svg-container svg {
  background: lightblue;
}

#svg-container svg path {
  fill: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
<!-- See: https://gist.github.com/rmkane/4fb74736f090d9145b53e56d7e42989e#file-world-2-svg -->
```